# How to log time taken by rest calls in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, ngresource

I am using [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) to call our backend server APIs in my AngularJs app. I was looking for ways to log outgoing requests at the time of initiation and when the response comes, along with the time taken by that request. Please let me know if there is some module or custom code which can do it. I tried to search online but didn't got any solution.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the Network panel of the developer tools of your browser, which does that for you (and provides more details)? Anyway, you can just use an interceptor to do that: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Comment: @JBNizet I was doing that, but there was huge difference between time shown for those APIs in browser and time taken as par server logs, so I thought to get data around it from UI server which should be more reliable, Any comments on this?

Comment: @JBNizet WIll check out the link shared by you, Thanks.

Comment: Well, the server and the browser don't measure the same thing. The server measures the time it takes between the moment it has received the request and the moment it has generated a response (most probably). The browser dev tools shows the time it takes to make the DNS lookup (if any), wait before being allowed to send the request (a browser typically doesn't  send more than 6 concurrent requests to the same server), send the request over the network, wait for the response that must also travel over the network, and finally handle the response. So, it's quite normal to have a difference.

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to do....question says one thing...client side time but comments mention logging server processing time. Requires separate operations

Comment: @charlietfl: What I wanted was exact time taken by my angular app to hit a rest API and return response.